# Wordpress: Increment time value by second(s) with MySQL query (duplicate post date + timestamp)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need your help.
I'm trying to increment the post time for all posts by 1 seconds (or few seconds) in the MySQL database to get unique timestamp for every post.

I have the following query:

```
set  @rownum =0;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date=DATE_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL+(@rownum := @rownum +1) SECOND);
```

It almost works but the time will be incremented by 5 days. I don't get why so.

I would be very grateful for any tips.

Comment: If the value for `@rownum` is between 432000 and 518400, then it would make sense that 5 days are added.  If you want to add 1 second, why are you adding `INTERVAL+(@rownum := @rownum +1)` seconds ?  and what is the output of `SELECT @rownum` after  the UPDATE ?

Comment: or, how many rows are there in `wp_posts` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are 401598 rows in wp_posts. Unfortunately I'm not an MySQL expert. Is there a simple query for that? :)

Comment: I also commented: " why are you adding `INTERVAL+(@rownum := @rownum +1) seconds` ?"   Did you try to replace `INTERVAL+(@rownum := @rownum +1) seconds` with `INTERVAL 1 SECOND` , to just add 1 second ?

Comment: With ```UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date=DATE_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL 1 SECOND);``` all rows will be incremented by 1 second. But how to increment it in this way:

```2021-09-25 07:00:06
2021-09-25 07:00:07
2021-09-25 07:00:08```

Comment: You want to have a unique time?  What is the version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: Correct :) mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 2):

this shuold list all `post_date` with an extra column with the value that you can use in the increment:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   post_date,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by post_date)-1 as incrementValue
FROM wp_posts
```

If the incrementValues are OK (i.e. not over 60), you can update your `wp_posts` with:

```
UPDATE wp_posts w
JOIN (
   SELECT
      ID, 
      post_date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by post_date)-1 as incrementValue
   FROM wp_posts ) x ON x.ID = w.ID
SET w.post_date = DATE_ADD(w.post_date, INTERVAL x.incrementValue SECOND)
```

Note: above is untested, so you should make sure that you have a backup, and know how to restore it in case of failure.

Maybe it is needed to reset the seconds to 0 with the next UPDATE:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_date = DATA_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL -second(post_date) SECOND)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but there are some syntax errors in the query that I can't fix. Maybe it is easier to change the hours AND minutes AND seconds to random values for each post/row (without changing the date/the date shouldn't be changed). So the probability that the posts get the same timestamp would be very low.

Comment: oops, my fault, I now see that I typed `partion`, which should be `partition`

Comment: and the other error is also fixed (about: "Column 'post_date' in field list is ambiguous" )

Comment: Perfect! You are the man! I am very pleased, worked like a charm. Thank you very, very much! It will also help other people for sure (unique answer on net).

Duplicate date+timestamp = trouble with next/previous posts

Upvoted and recorded, as soon as I have 15 reputation. 
Have a nice weekend. ;-)